# Debug a compiled Java Equinox program

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, osgi, equinox

Is there a way to debug a Java application that is started via Eclipse Equinox?
Something similar to the ".net reflector" does with C #.
We have this big program that was developed years ago by an internal team and we have to understand how it works so that we can reacreate it in another language.
The problem is that we haven't got any sorce code file (everything was lost).

Right now the directory of the application contains:
- Dir "configuration"
- Dir "integration"
- Dir "plugins"
- Dir "tools"
- Dir "workspace"
- starter.exe (with eclipse logo as icon)
- starter.ini
- startup.jar

I really hope that there is a way to retrive how the app worked.

Thanks :)

Comment: I think a java decompiler is what you need, take a look at [this](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/07/5-best-java-decompilers.html)

Comment: @niceman I have already tried jd-gui, but it doesn't work with apps that are using equinox (the program is starting from an exe). Plus it doesn't allow me to debug attaching to the running exe / jar

Comment: java Decompilers takes .class files not .exe(they may accept .jar file because a jar file is just an archive containing .class files), if jd-gui didn't accept a jar file, unarchive it(Right click -> Extract) to get the .class files.

Comment: @niceman Yes, i know that.. The problem is that the program that i'm trying to debug, is built using Equinox. So i only have a launcher.exe file and a bunch of jar in the plugin folder. Nothing else

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not at osgi, I don't know how to decompile this :(

Comment: OSGi is irrelevant. You need a java decompiler (jd-gui should work fine). Just point it at the JARs in the plugin folder. There will be no interesting code in the launcher.exe. Java code is shipped in JAR files, not EXEs.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Thank you Neil! But is there any way to debug these jars in a similar way as the .net reflector does? We have 180+ jars inside the plugin directory O_O

Comment: @titanicsnake All of the popular Java IDEs (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ) have built-in debuggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i managed to resolve my problem. Here what i did:

- Downloaded Eclipse Mars (4.5.2)
- In Eclipse, i've selected "Help" -> "Install new software" and added the repository site "mchr3k - http://mchr3k-eclipse.appspot.com/".
- From here i've downloaded the "Java decompiler Eclipse Plug-in"
- Created a new temporary java project and added all the .jar i wanted to debug to the build path of the project.
- Added this line in the "launcher.ini" contained in the directory of the application i wanted to debug: "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8888,server=y,suspend=n"
- Started a "Remote debug" from Eclipse

By doing this i can attach the eclipse debugger to my application and use the decompild source code.